# Multiple videojs players in the same react component

Tags: reactjs, video.js

Working on react app (Step-By-Step Assembly Instructions), showing onClick some movies. Any step could contain 1 to 6 movies. Can't map movie paths (sources) to multiple videojs players.

I would like to dinamically show some movies in react component using videojs. I'm using example ( https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-react.html ) from videojs as a template. Everything work just fine with a static scene - separate 'videoJsOptions' with sources known in advance, and separate  components... When I'm trying to dynamically create VideoPlayers within the map or foreach, I have a problem's trying to create const in every step of the loop. E.g. how to create dynamic const's name...
So, could anybody help me - how to map movies from the state?

```
{this.state.movies.map(themovie => {
    rbr++;
    this["something"+rbr] = {
    autoplay: false,
    controls: true,
    height: 320,
    width: 480,
    sources: [{
        src: {themovie},
        type: 'video/mp4'
    }]
};
    return <VideoPlayer { ...this["something"+rbr] } key={rbr} />;
})}
```

The error, I'm receiving, is: "VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible source was found for this media."

Answer (score 0):

I should never post a question in the evening. Things look better in the morning. Just removed curly braces and everything is just fine.

```
src: themovie
```

BTW, is there any smarter way to map a filename paths to the dinamically created players?